# Retrieve Data Extension based on ObjectID using SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, php, marketingcloudapi

Using the Marketing Cloud API I'm trying to programmatically determine the fields in an event definition. So...

1. I can start with the ID of the journey and get the journey definition with `/interaction/v1/interactions/{{JOURNEYID}}`
2. From there I can get the eventDefinitionId and call `/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/{{EVENTDEFINITIONID}}`
3. And now I am stuck! I can't get the External/Customer Key for the data extension that houses the data for the event definition. I can **only** get the `dataExtensionId` and `dataExtensionName` values.

It looks like I need to use the SOAP API to retrieve the list of fields in a Data Extension, but I can't seem to create the `simpleFilterPart` that uses `ObjectID`. It only seems to work when using the `CustomerKey` value! (I've tested on DE's where I just grab the External Key from the UI)

[image: Get Event Definition Response]

Here's a snippet of the code I'm playing with. I can't get any other filter "property" to work!

```php
        $getDE = new ET_DataExtension();
        $getDE->authStub = $myclient;
        $getDE->props = array("CustomerKey", "Name", "Status", "CategoryID", "Description", "IsSendable", "IsTestable", "PartnerKey");  
        $getDE->filter = array('Property' => 'CustomerKey','SimpleOperator' => 'equals','Value' => $de_key);
        $getResult = $getDE->get();
        print_r('Get Status: '.($getResult->status ? 'true' : 'false')."\n");
        print 'Code: '.$getResult->code."\n";
        print 'Message: '.$getResult->message."\n";
        print_r('More Results: '.($getResult->moreResults ? 'true' : 'false')."\n");
        print 'Result Count: '.count($getResult->results)."\n";
        print 'Results: '."\n";
        print_r($getResult->results);
        print "\n---------------\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after doing some research the only field you can use is `DataExtension.CustomerKey` in your filter, none of the other fields are supported such as `id`, `objectid`, or `name`

So you would first need to do a retrieve on the DataExtension Object

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>DataRetentionPeriod</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>DataRetentionPeriodLength</Properties>
            <Properties>DataRetentionPeriodUnitOfMeasure</Properties>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>ObjectID</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>XXXXXXXX</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
```